# How to interface with a Nintendo WiiMote through Python 3.3?

Tags: python, ubuntu, bluetooth, python-3.3, wiimote

I am trying to read the button states and accelerometer and IR camera values with Python 3.3 but none of the ways that I have tried work. The first way is through Bluetooth sockets with this code:

```
import socket

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MAC = '00:1F:C5:35:91:5A'
    blue = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
    wm = blue.connect((MAC,1))
```

But this always generates errors. When the computer is already paired to the WiiMote I get `No route to host`, when I'm not connected but visible I get `Operation now in progress` and when I'm not visible I get `Connection reset by peer`.

I'm able to read the button states with `pygame.joystick` and `cat /dev/input/js0` but this leaves me unable to send requests to the WiiMote which allow me to read the accelerometer and IR camera values.

The are also modules such as CWiiD and PyWiiUse but are only compatable  with Python 2.x. I have also tried using the HID to send these requests but the modules install for Python 2.7 even though I don't have that version of Python installed.

Is there any way that this task can be accomplished? I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on a 64 bit Intel i5 and the solution doesn't need to platform independent.